# MySQL: Select from table only a result by username

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with test results, which is composed in this way:

```
+-----------------------+
| id | score | username |
+-----------------------+
| 1  |    15 |     mike |
| 2  |    23 |     tom  |
| 3  |    16 |     mike |

etc..
```

I want to select only one result for each username, but the one with the highest score.

The output should be so:

```
Mike: 16
Tom:  23
```

How to do so?

Comment: You need to do a SELECT username , max(score) and GROUP BY username. Look here for details http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: @mt025 what if I have to order it by score then?

Comment: @Northumber Just add a `order by score` or `order by score DESC` clause for descending.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `group by` clause to get only one result per user. E.g.:

```
SELECT     username, MAX(score)
FROM       results
GROUP BY   username
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```